# In Fat Free Framework how i can parse an arbitrary ini file and add it to the hive?

Tags: php, ini, fat-free-framework

After my application has started up, in certain circumstances I want to bulk load some data into the hive inside a controller.

Is there an easy way for me to import a .ini file into the hive that is not a config.ini or routes.ini file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:

```
$f3->config('abc/def.ini');
echo $f3->get('foo');//bar
echo $f3->get('arr.key');//123
```

abc/def.ini:

```
foo=bar
arr.key=123
```

NB: the method's name `config()` might be misleading but it's there to parse ini files.

Comment: So, as long as I don't redefine the config.ini values, then my original values will be ok, and this will only append/replace in the hive?

Comment: Each line leads to a `$f3->set($key,$val)` statement. So: if you declare a new variable, it will be created; if you declare an existing variable, it will be replaced.